# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type User\Entity\User as array

Tags: php, zend-framework, zfcuser, zfdoctrine

The problem is:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
<?php $user = $user[0] ?>
```

error:

```
=> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type User\Entity\User as array in ../module/User/view/user/index/index.phtml
```

My class is:

```
class IndexController extends ApplicationController
{
/**
 * Store the user.
 * @var \User\Entity\User
 */
protected $_user;



public function indexAction()
{
    $offset = 6;
    $page = $this->params()->fromQuery('page');
    if (!$page) {
        $page = 1;
    }

    $dql = "SELECT
            users
         FROM User\Entity\User users

        GROUP BY users.id
        ORDER BY " . $this->getOrderDql();

    $query = $this->objectManager()
        ->createQuery($dql)
        ->setFirstResult(($page - 1) * $offset)
        ->setMaxResults($offset);

    $users = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);
    $quantity = (int) ceil($users->count() / $offset);

    return new ViewModel(
        array(
            'users' => $users,
            'offset' => $offset,
            'page' => $page,
            'quantity' => $quantity,
            'order' => $this->getOrderValue(),
        )
    );
}

}
```

Thanks for the answers!

(text to make my post not mostly code)

Comment: How do you initialize `$users` object? Show us that code.

Comment: @AmalMurali it's use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;
$users = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);

Answer (score 0):

as the error says you `cant` use the object as array,

you need to access the object as following way,

`$user->'keyname';` or `$user->'filedname'` instead of `$user[0]`;

where keyname or field name is name of your field that you want to retrieve.

Comment: it gives me syntax error when I replace $user[0] with $user->'something'

Comment: what is the error? and can you show the content of $users ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $users is array of $user. So when using foreach $user becomes single instance of an array of user-fields. Then you have to access fields like this

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
<?php $id = $user['id'] ?>
```